# WordPress: Always create an image for custom image size, even if the uploaded image is smaller than the custom size

Tags: wordpress

I want to generate an extra image size in WordPress. WP lets you use `add_image_size` like this:

```
// Make sure featured images are enabled
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

// Add featured image sizes
add_image_size( 'original-img', 2000, 99999 );
```

If the image has the min. width of 2000px, the image size will be generated. 
However if the image is smaller the custom size won't be generated.

Is there any option to create an image for the custom image size **everytime**, no matter of the uploaded image size? Or maybe its possible to additionally save the original image?

To explain why I am trying to achieve:  I need a watermark on my images, but need also the original image (or a very big image) as well without the watermark.

I also tried with the "large" image, but here the same problem. By uploading an image smaller than 1024px, the image size wouldn't be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook into `wp_generate_attachment_metadata` and make a copy of the uploaded image there if it wasn't already created. I've included the code to do this below.

Add this to your functions.php. Each step is commented to explain what its doing, but basically during the upload process:

- we check if WP created your custom size
- If it was, do nothing
- Otherwise create a copy of the image called imagename-WxH.extn (e.g.if the uploaded image was cat.jpg and was 700x520px, our copy will be called `cat-700x520px.jpg`)
- Add the copied image as your custom size `original-img`

Then you can use your `original-img` custom size in your code and always have an image.

```
// Make sure featured images are enabled
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

// Add featured image sizes
add_image_size( 'original-img', 2000, 99999 );


// Hook into the upload process
add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata','copy_original_img');
// Check if the original image was added, if not make a copy and add it as original-img
function copy_original_img($image_data) {

    // if the original-img was created, we don't need to do anything
    if (isset($image_data['sizes']['original-img']))
        return;

    // 1. make a copy of the uploaded image to use for original-img

    $upload_dir     = wp_upload_dir();
    $uploaded_img   = $image_data['file'];
    $img_w          = $image_data['width'];
    $img_h          = $image_data['height'];

    // construct the filename for the copy in the format: imagename-WxH.extn
    $path_parts = pathinfo($uploaded_img);
    $new_img = $path_parts['filename']."-".$img_w."x".$img_h.".".$path_parts['extension'];

    // make a copy of the image 
    $img_to_copy = $upload_dir['path'] . '/'.$uploaded_img;
    $new_img_path = $upload_dir['path'] . '/'.$new_img;
    $success = copy($img_to_copy,$new_img_path);


    // 2. If the image was copied successfully, add it into the image_data to be returned:
    if ($success){
        $image_data['sizes']['original-img']['file']        = $new_img;
        $image_data['sizes']['original-img']['width']       = $img_w ; // same as uploaded width
        $image_data['sizes']['original-img']['height']      = $img_h; // same as uploaded height
        $image_data['sizes']['original-img']['mime-type']   = mime_content_type($new_img_path);
    }

    return $image_data;
}
```